# Volume mounts, but windows can access raw file system

Tags: truecrypt

Truecrypt accepts my password and mounts the drive, but when I go to access it, it tells me it's an invalid drive. Tried to use testdisk, but it wouldn't work due to it being a raw drive. I would love to get this data back, any help would be greatly appreciated.